# How can I make a function that can accept 6 arguments in which 3 will be optional

Tags: python, console

I am making a small project in python, console on'library management system'. In which I want to add add_customer() function to add new login in database.
So while adding new customer function will take arguments like f_name,m_name,l_name,ph_no, address, password. I want to keep ph_no and address as optional arguments. So while calling function if i didn't give these two or any one parameter then also code should work.
How can I make this like code?

Comment: Use default values like `None` for your optional parameters, and then define your function body to handle that the way you wish. We can't decide that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the function, put the required arguments before the optional ones.  Put the optional arguments at the end, with default values.

example:

```
def my_function(req_arg1, req_arg2, req_arg3, opt_arg1=None, opt_arg2=0.0, opt_arg3=False):
   """ req_arg1, req_arg2 and req_arg3 are required
       opt_arg1, opt_arg2, and opt_arg3 are optional and have default values """
    ...
```